# why argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable is shown in my program

Tags: python, python-2.7

i made this hangman program but it is giving 'nonetype' error whenever i run it
program running-
Whenever I enter a word the output is like this
           Hang Man Game
    Guess a word
    a
    -----
    You gussed one word correctly

```
 -----a---------------

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/coding/python/python programming for absolute beginners/chapter 5/Hang Man Game.py", line 129, in <module>
    if guess  in used:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

The code:

```
print("\t\t\tHang Man Game")
import random
set=("happy","australia","punjab","criclet","tennis")
choose=random.choice(set)
correct=choose
HANGMAN=('''
_______
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
 |
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |     |
 |     |
 |     |
 |     |
 |     
 |     
 |     
 |     
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |     |
 |  ---|
 |     |  
 |     |
 |    
 |   
 |  
 |     
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |     |
 |  ---|---
 |     |  
 |     |
 |  
 |   
 |  
 |     
___
''',
         '''

______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |     |
 |  ---|---
 |     |  
 |     |
 |    / 
 |   /   
 |  /     
 |     
___
''',
         '''
______________
 |     |
 |     O
 |     |
 |  ---|---
 |     |  
 |     |
 |    / \
 |   /   \
 |  /     \
 |     
___
'''
         )
MAX_WRONG=(len(HANGMAN)-1)
wrong=0
new=""
used=[]
so_far="-"*len(correct)
guess=raw_input("Guess a word\n")
while(so_far!=correct and wrong<MAX_WRONG):
    print(so_far)
    if guess  in used:
        print("you have already used it")     
    else:
        if guess in correct:
            print("You gussed one word correctly\n")
            used.append(guess)
            for i in range(len(correct)):
                if  guess==correct[i]:
                    new=new+guess
                else:
                    new=new+so_far
            so_far=new
        else:
            used=used.append(guess)
            wrong=wrong+1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this

```
used = used.append(guess)
```

The `append` function returns `None`, it modifies `used` in place. So you are basically appending `guess` on the right hand side, but then assigning `None` to `used`. So the next iteration of the `while` loop you are trying to iterate over `None`, which is what the error is telling you.

You simply need to say

```
used.append(guess)
```

Or

```
used += [guess]
```

Comment: still it is giving error

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Did you fix the *two* occurrences of `append` in your code? (It works for me)

Comment: yes i did that but that dash loop
for i in range(len(correct)):
                if  guess==correct[i]:
                    new=new+guess
                else:
                    new=new+so_far
            so_far=new
 is giving problem

Comment: @ShubhamSharma If it is not the same problem anymore, then I think you should ask a new question (but be sure that you really tried to debug your code before asking about it).

Answer (score 0):

The member function `append` of `list` modifies the list in place and does not return anything.

At the first iteration, `used` is an empty list, but when you reach the line `used=used.append(guess)`, `used` is first modified by `append` as you expect it to be, *and then* you assign the return value of `append` (which is `None`) to `used`. Thus, in the second iteration, `used` is `None`.

Simply change the two lines using `append` for `used.append(guess)`.

There are other problems with your code though, one of them being that you ask for a guess only once (you can put the `guess = raw_input("Guess a word\n")` in the loop instead).